# fast reading with fread without using fwrite

Tags: c, fread

I have a graph in the following format:

```
3 15 12
15 15
12 35
12 54
```

where the first line is some info about the graph and the first letter on the first line is the number of edges. The following m lines are the edges.
I can easily read this file with scanf. But now I am looking to understand fread to read all the edges at once and not each line one at a time.

```
int main () {
int32_t row1[3];

printf("row1[0]=%d, row1[1]=%d, row1[2]=%d\n", row1[0], row1[1], row1[2]);
FILE* in;
in = fopen("in", "r");
fread(&row1, sizeof(int32_t), 3, in);

fclose(in);
printf("row1[0]=%d, row1[1]=%d, row1[2]=%d\n", row1[0], row1[1], row1[2]);
}
```

But I do not get the output 3, 15, 12 as I expect from the last printf.

Do you need to create the in file with fwrite or can you create it in any way?

Comment: If your input is lines of text, `fread` is *definitely* not what you want.  `fgets`, maybe.

Comment: `fread` is for binary files. You have a text file. Anyway, it's pointless to worry about the speed of reading such a tiny file. If you are going to make a change it should be for other reasons.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: if you source file is in binary then copying the raw data is what you want. But if you have a text file then you need something like `fscanf` to not just read but also parse the data. You can also read the whole file at once and then parse buffer in memory with i.e. `sscanf`

Comment: @IlDeSanta If you don't understand the difference between a *text file* and a *binary file*, you need to learn that now.

Comment: @kaylum OFC my files are much larger just did a small file to understand the principle. OK so then I got to create my graphs with fwrite and then this should work?

Comment: OK I understand the problem thanks!

Comment: Also understand you are reading TEXT. ASCII digits. If you read with `fread` you will have to isolate each set of digits and convert from ASCII digits to an integer value. Reading with `fgets()` into a buffer and parsing with `sscanf()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to read the whole file at once. It can be done like this. I omitted error checking for malloc and fread.

```
fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
size_t size = ftell(in);
rewind(in);
char buffer = malloc(size);
fread(buffer, size, 1, in);
```

But then you need to parse the buffer. There's not much to gain from this. If you want to read a text file, then `fgets` is usually the way to go. Reading line by line with `fread` makes little sense. The function is intended for binary files. You would have to manually search for line breaks.